# TOC page # prefix

Tags: table-of-contents

Is there a way to add a prefix to the page Number in the TOC? The page number in the footer is based on the cover page. I have a "StyleRef" on the cover page indicating the volume # that automatically populates the footer page number with the volume #, example II-2. How can I get the TOC to pickup the volume # without manually inserting the volume #?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I created a style named "S_9 TP Volume Number" & inserted it to the footer page # (using Field function ["StyleRef"] and picking the "S_9 TP Volume Number" style, so it will pickup the volume # I enter on the Cover Page. If the volume # is II then the II will appear in the footer next to the page # with a dash before it, (II-1). But when I run the TOC, it will only pick up the page # and I have to manually type the Volume # (II). Is there a way to get the TOC to also insert the volume #?